# Buildfire - How to load sorted pages dynamically from publicData/datastore

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to lazy load data from publicData using the options that BuildFire describes in the wiki.  I have set up some code to test that it works and it seems that is does not any way that I configure the request options.  Here is the code that I am using:

```
     var loadSortedPages = function(page) {
      var skip = page*50;
      var options = {
        "filter": {},
        "sort": {"points": 1},
        "pageSize": "50",
        "skip": skip.toString()
      }
      buildfire.publicData.search(options, 'users', function(err, records) {
        console.log("RECORDS SORTED ASCENDING BY POINTS FOR PAGE " + page, records);
      });
    }

    loadSortedPages(0);
    loadSortedPages(1);
    loadSortedPages(2);
```

I have tried, it seems, every thinkable combination of "page" and "skip" both as different combinations of string and number values.  Nothing works and I always get back the first 50 sorted records for each of the loadSortedPages calls even though I am passing in different page numbers.  If this something on BuildFire's end?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on how to use Datastore search https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Datastore#buildfiredatastoresearchoptions-tag-optional-callback

It seems like you are mixing to pagination methods:

> and for pagination you can either use:
>
> page : is number that determine the page that need to retrieve.
>
> pageSize: is a number of record per page , the max value is 20.
>
> **Or** use:
>
> skip : is number of record that you need to skip.
>
> limit: is a number
> of record for this call, the max value is 20.